# Erroneous video output from mvp using VAAPI hardware decoding

Tags: debian, video, intel-graphics, vaapi

I own a laptop with Intel HD graphics (`i915` kernel driver) and I'm trying to get hardware-accelerated video playback under Debian Jessie. I have installed `i965-va-driver` and `libva-intel-vaapi-driver` packages, and `vainfo` gives me a list of supported codecs:

```
$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.36.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_36
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.36 (libva 1.4.1)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) CherryView - 1.4.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
  VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
  ...
```

Yet when I try to play a video with `mpv --hwdec=vaapi filename`, I get a totally broken video output:

[image]

Now, the picture does change with the rhythm which matches the audio, suggesting the decoding does happen, but the result is completely unusable. Does anyone happen to have experience with accelerated video on Intel hardware? Any ideas of what I could be doing wrong?

Here's what my `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` says:

```
[    11.754] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Cherryview (gen8) backend
[    11.755] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[    11.755] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    11.755] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[    11.755] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[    11.756] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[    11.757] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[    11.757] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    11.757] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[    11.757] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[    11.757] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[    11.757] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
```

Comment: I'd see what xorg thinks about the card, `grep -A 10 -B 10 Accel ~/local/share/xorg/Xorg*log` would be a start.  But I need to admit that I never used video acceleration on a intel card.

Comment: @grochmal I added some information to my question, see if that's relevant.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is trying a newer kernel.  You tagged your question with jessie, which is using kernel 3.18 (i believe).  I can find the driver for cherry view in the [4.7 kernel codebase](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-cherryview.c?v=4.7) but cannot find it in the [3.18 codebase](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/pinctrl/intel/pinctrl-cherryview.c?v=3.18)